# View XML-Data as Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a Table (`DAT_Detail`) in SQL Server 2008R2 with a XML-Column. In the XML-Column there is detailed information for some tests... (I cannot change the table to another design, it has to stay as XML).
My table has 2 columns: `DAT_Detail_ID` (unique identifier) and `XMLDetaildata` (XML).

This is the script to add my test data:

```
INSERT INTO DAT_Detail (DAT_Detail_ID, XMLDetaildata) VALUES ('629E4F85-098D-418B-BF2E-63648DCF60ED', '<NewDataSet><DetailTest_A10><TestValue1>1321</TestValue1><TestValue2>142</TestValue2><TestValue3>153</TestValue3><TestValue4>1645</TestValue4><TestValue5>1123</TestValue5><TestValue6>114</TestValue6><TestValue7>1253</TestValue7></DetailTest_A10></NewDataSet>');
INSERT INTO DAT_Detail (DAT_Detail_ID, XMLDetaildata) VALUES ('9B30DDAF-0733-4D0D-BCBD-54DA3B56C8F9', '<NewDataSet><DetailTest_A10><TestValue1>2321</TestValue1><TestValue2>242</TestValue2><TestValue3>253</TestValue3><TestValue4>2645</TestValue4><TestValue5>2123</TestValue5><TestValue6>214</TestValue6><TestValue7>2253</TestValue7></DetailTest_A10></NewDataSet>');
INSERT INTO DAT_Detail (DAT_Detail_ID, XMLDetaildata) VALUES ('E647B9FB-7B96-440A-ADCB-300F8DEA4BF1', '<NewDataSet><DetailTest_A10><TestValue1>3321</TestValue1><TestValue2>342</TestValue2><TestValue3>353</TestValue3><TestValue4>3645</TestValue4><TestValue5>3123</TestValue5><TestValue6>314</TestValue6><TestValue7>3253</TestValue7></DetailTest_A10></NewDataSet>');
INSERT INTO DAT_Detail (DAT_Detail_ID, XMLDetaildata) VALUES ('50041AE4-BE73-4281-A36E-7448F6F35E03', '<NewDataSet><DetailTest_A10><TestValue1>4321</TestValue1><TestValue2>442</TestValue2><TestValue3>453</TestValue3><TestValue4>4645</TestValue4><TestValue5>4123</TestValue5><TestValue6>414</TestValue6><TestValue7>4253</TestValue7></DetailTest_A10></NewDataSet>');
INSERT INTO DAT_Detail (DAT_Detail_ID, XMLDetaildata) VALUES ('87AE23BA-41DE-4C1E-BA4E-37E7C3419FE3', '<NewDataSet><DetailTest_A10><TestValue1>5321</TestValue1><TestValue2>542</TestValue2><TestValue3>553</TestValue3><TestValue4>5645</TestValue4><TestValue5>5123</TestValue5><TestValue6>514</TestValue6><TestValue7>5253</TestValue7></DetailTest_A10></NewDataSet>');
INSERT INTO DAT_Detail (DAT_Detail_ID, XMLDetaildata) VALUES ('9AAEA106-35C9-40B8-B0D5-7CA7F59E5D90', '<NewDataSet><DetailTest_A10><TestValue1>6321</TestValue1><TestValue2>642</TestValue2><TestValue3>653</TestValue3><TestValue4>6645</TestValue4><TestValue5>6123</TestValue5><TestValue6>614</TestValue6><TestValue7>6253</TestValue7></DetailTest_A10></NewDataSet>');
```

What I want is to select 2 or more rows and convert the XML to a table-format to show the values in a report in a `SQLReportServer`.

I have a query for translate XML to table but I can only use 1 row for this. As soon as I try to take more rows, only the last row is translated to a table.

My Script:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML
DECLARE @hDoc AS INT

SELECT @XML = XMLDetaildata FROM DAT_Detail WHERE DAT_Detail_ID = '9B30DDAF-0733-4D0D-BCBD-54DA3B56C8F9'
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'NewDataSet/DetailTest_A10')
WITH 
(
TestValue1 [int] 'TestValue1',
TestValue2 [int] 'TestValue2',
TestValue3 [int] 'TestValue3',
TestValue4 [int] 'TestValue4',
TestValue5 [int] 'TestValue5',
TestValue6 [int] 'TestValue6',
TestValue7 [int] 'TestValue7'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

What I get is a table:

```
TestValue1  TestValue2  TestValue3  TestValue4  TestValue5  TestValue6  TestValue7
2321        242         253         2645        2123        214         2253
```

I tried to change my script to:

```
SELECT @XML = XMLDetaildata FROM DAT_Detail WHERE DAT_Detail_ID IN ( '9B30DDAF-0733-4D0D-BCBD-54DA3B56C8F9', '50041AE4-BE73-4281-A36E-7448F6F35E03')
```

to get this:

```
TestValue1  TestValue2  TestValue3  TestValue4  TestValue5  TestValue6  TestValue7
2321        242         253         2645        2123        214         2253    
4321        442         453         4645        4123        414         4253
```

but it failed... has anyone another idea to get me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you describe failed?

Comment: Definetly one variable `@XML` can not hold 2 values. Add`ORDER BY DAT_Detail_ID  ASC  / DESC` to be sure which one of two you get.

Comment: @SeanLange I failed means i could not find a way to rewrite the query to get the result i wanted... But all the 3 folowing answers working perfectly, i had to choose one. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select B.*
 From  Dat_Detail A
 Cross Apply (
                Select TestValue1 = B.value('TestValue1[1]','int') 
                      ,TestValue2 = B.value('TestValue2[1]','int') 
                      ,TestValue3 = B.value('TestValue3[1]','int') 
                      ,TestValue4 = B.value('TestValue4[1]','int') 
                      ,TestValue5 = B.value('TestValue5[1]','int') 
                      ,TestValue6 = B.value('TestValue6[1]','int') 
                      ,TestValue7 = B.value('TestValue7[1]','int') 
                 From  XMLDetaildata.nodes('/NewDataSet') AS A(Grp)
                 Cross Apply A.Grp.nodes('DetailTest_A10') AS B(B)
             ) B
 Where DAT_Detail_ID  IN ( '9B30DDAF-0733-4D0D-BCBD-54DA3B56C8F9', '50041AE4-BE73-4281-A36E-7448F6F35E03')
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: Thx, i took your solution because it worked perfectly and i could apply it to my real table (the one above was an example). The best part is, i removed the where clause and the query only took the rows where this specific test was asked. I have much more different Tests and i now write for each Test 1 specific query and the query only shows the affected rows. Really NICE!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this kind of solution:

```
SELECT  TestValue1,
        TestValue2,
        TestValue3,
        TestValue4,
        TestValue5,
        TestValue6,
        TestValue7
FROM (
    SELECT  dd.DAT_Detail_ID,
            CAST(t.c.query('local-name(.)') as nvarchar(max)) as [Columns],
            t.c.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as [Values]
    FROM DAT_Detail dd
    CROSS APPLY XMLDetaildata.nodes('/NewDataSet/DetailTest_A10/*') as t(c)
    WHERE dd.DAT_Detail_ID IN (
    '9B30DDAF-0733-4D0D-BCBD-54DA3B56C8F9',
    '50041AE4-BE73-4281-A36E-7448F6F35E03')
) t
PIVOT (
    MAX([Values]) FOR [Columns] IN (TestValue1,TestValue2,TestValue3,TestValue4,TestValue5,TestValue6,TestValue7)
) as pvt
```

Output:

```
TestValue1  TestValue2  TestValue3  TestValue4  TestValue5  TestValue6  TestValue7
4321        442         453         4645        4123        414         4253
2321        242         253         2645        2123        214         2253
```

Or:

```
SELECT  t.c.value('(*)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as TestValue1,
        t.c.value('(*)[2]','nvarchar(max)') as TestValue2,
        t.c.value('(*)[3]','nvarchar(max)') as TestValue3,
        t.c.value('(*)[4]','nvarchar(max)') as TestValue4,
        t.c.value('(*)[5]','nvarchar(max)') as TestValue5,
        t.c.value('(*)[6]','nvarchar(max)') as TestValue6,
        t.c.value('(*)[7]','nvarchar(max)') as TestValue7
FROM DAT_Detail dd
CROSS APPLY XMLDetaildata.nodes('/NewDataSet/DetailTest_A10') as t(c)
WHERE dd.DAT_Detail_ID IN (
'9B30DDAF-0733-4D0D-BCBD-54DA3B56C8F9',
'50041AE4-BE73-4281-A36E-7448F6F35E03')
```

Comment: This solution also worked for me... thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use xml functions instead

```
SELECT n.x.value('TestValue1[1]', 'INT') as TestValue1, n.x.value('TestValue2[1]', 'INT') as TestValue2 --, ...
FROM  DAT_Detail
CROSS APPLY XMLDetaildata.nodes('/NewDataSet/DetailTest_A10') n(x)
WHERE DAT_Detail_ID IN ('9B30DDAF-0733-4D0D-BCBD-54DA3B56C8F9', '50041AE4-BE73-4281-A36E-7448F6F35E03')
```

Comment: This solution also worked for me... thanks for your help.